# Pull domain mapping in bootstrap and modify it Grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, hibernate-mapping, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am currently using Grails-2.2.4, I would like to modify the behaviour of my domain mapping from bootstrap to alter the dateCreated Field to custom date. While trying to pull the mapping of domain to modify the autotimestamp behaviour, the GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping is returning null. Am I missing something, here is my code

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { gdc ->
        def domClass = gdc.clazz
        def grailsSave = domClass.metaClass.pickMethod('save', [Map] as Class[])

        domClass.metaClass.save = { Map params ->

            def m = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(domClass.class)
            println("The mapping ===>>>$m") /* **this gives Null**   */
            m.autoTimestamp = false
            def colList = []
            domClass.declaredFields.each{
                if(!it.synthetic)
                    colList.add(it.name.toString())
            }
            if(colList.contains("dateCreated")) {
                println(domClass.metaClass.getProperty(delegate,"dateCreated"));
                domClass.metaClass.setProperty(delegate,"dateCreated",new Date("11/5/1990"))
                grailsSave.invoke(delegate, [params] as Object[])
            }

            //...
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error

```
Cannot set property 'autoTimestamp' on null object
```

Comment: Please change `domClass.newInstance().class` to `domClass`. It won't help with your question but it's completely useless to create an instance of a Class so you can find out what the instance's class is.

Comment: I knew that but, any suggestion on the answer although.. :)

Answer (score 3):

I found out what I was doing wrong, the domain object returned from the domainClasses.clazz was not returning a GrailsDomainClass but default java class object which is not what it needed. Using delegate instead of domClass worked.
Here is the working code cheers :) ..

```
grailsApplication.domainClasses.each { gdc ->
    def domClass = gdc.clazz
    def grailsSave = domClass.metaClass.pickMethod('save', [Map] as Class[])

    domClass.metaClass.save = { Map params ->

        def m = GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(delegate.getDomainClass())
        println("The mapping ===>>>$m") 
        m.autoTimestamp = false
        def colList = []
        domClass.declaredFields.each{
            if(!it.synthetic)
                colList.add(it.name.toString())
        }
        if(colList.contains("dateCreated")) {
            println(domClass.metaClass.getProperty(delegate,"dateCreated"));
            domClass.metaClass.setProperty(delegate,"dateCreated",new Date("11/5/1990"))
            grailsSave.invoke(delegate, [params] as Object[])
        }

        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating with the answer. One note, in Grails 2.4+, the getMapping function is no longer static - you'll need to create an instance of GrailsDomainBinder for it to work!